# How to create a link to another PHP page

Tags: php, html, templates, hyperlink, anchor

I just converted some of my `HTML` pages to `PHP` pages, and I'm not that familiar with `PHP`. In my `HTML` pages, assuming it's just a static web app, I can link to another page quite simply by playing the following `anchor` on the page:

`<a href="go-to-this-page.html">This is a link</a>`

So, after converting the pages to `PHP` in order to make sure that I can template and include templates a bit easier and faster, I don't know how to include these links.

For example, say I have two pages, `index.php`, and `page2.php`. How would I create an anchor link to this page?

`<a href="??????">This is a link</a>`

Comment: `<a href="index.php">Index Page</a>`

Comment: It's exactly the same as the html link. The only difference is you echo the a tag in php

Comment: As like `<a href="index.php">Index Page</a>` if its in html page if its in php page you need to <?php echo '<a href="index.php">Index Page</a>';?>

Comment: Gah, I was being very stupid and made a mistake with the location of my development folder on Sublime. All working ok now! I just figured because I wasn't familiar with PHP that I had made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use like this

```
<a href="index.php">Index Page</a>
<a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest:

```
<a href="page2.php">Link</a>
```

And if you need to pass a value:

```
<a href="page2.php?val=1">Link that pass the value 1</a>
```

To retrive the value put in page2.php this code:

```
<?php
$val = $_GET["val"];
?>
```

Now the variable `$val` has the value `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Html a tag

Link in html

```
 <a href="index1.php">page1</a>
 <a href="page2.php">page2</a>
```

> Html in php

```
echo ' <a href="index1.php">page1</a>';
echo '<a href="page2.php">page2</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<a href='index.php'>Index Page</a>";
```

if you wanna use html tag like anchor tag you have to put in echo

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this:

> **HTML in PHP :**

```
$link_address1 = 'index.php';
echo "<a href='".$link_address1."'>Index Page</a>";

$link_address2 = 'page2.php';
echo "<a href='".$link_address2."'>Page 2</a>";
```

> Easiest way

```
$link_address1 = 'index.php';
echo "<a href='$link_address1'>Index Page</a>";

$link_address2 = 'page2.php';
echo "<a href='$link_address2'>Page 2</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used like this

```
<a href="<?php echo 'index.php'; ?>">Index Page</a>
<a href="<?php echo 'page2.php'; ?>">Page 2</a>
```