# PHP How to correctly echo a link?

Tags: php

What is the correct way to echo a link to another page in php? I have seen this used but it doesn't work?

```
 echo "<p><a href=\"link\">";
```

Comment: You should probably learn basic HTML  constructs before trying to generate it with PHP.  Just play with static pages first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a link to another PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387236/how-to-create-a-link-to-another-php-page)

Answer (score 1):

```
Html in PHP
<?php
echo "<a href='$link'>The Link You Want</a>";
?>

Php in Html
<a href="<?php echo $link;?>"> Link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question was already answered in [How to create a link to another PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387236/how-to-create-a-link-to-another-php-page)

```
<a href="index.php">Index Page</a>
<a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
```

If you need to pass a value -

```
<a href="page2.php?val=1">Link that pass the value 1</a>
```

Comment: No I am aware of how to make a link in HTML, I was questioning how one correctly echoes a link in php

Comment: I see, if you follow the link you'll find an answer towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this:

```
print("<a href='your_target'></a>");
```

Or if you want to print the code and not the link:

```
print(htmlspecialchars("<a href='your_target'></a>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href='<?php echo "the_page_you_want.php" ?>'>link_text</a>
```